# indexedDB idb library - insert multiple records

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, indexeddb

Using javascript Promises, i'm using the [idb](https://github.com/jakearchibald/idb) library to store data in indexedDB.  I am trying to figure out how to guarantee multiple 'adds' will be committed successfully before the transaction ends.

My question is which of the following is correct with regards to adding multiple records within one transaction:

```
var store = transaction.objectStore(...);
for(var i=0; i<records.length; i++) { store.add(records[i]); }
return transaction.complete;
```

or

```
var store = transaction.objectStore(...);
return Promise.all(records.map( record => { return store.add(record); }))
   .then( function () { return transaction.complete; });
```

which one guarantees all records will be added successfully before the transaction ends?  why?

Comment: Looks like both would work, and a transaction never completes while there are still operations running. You just need to have synchronously registered all the add operations before returning `transaction.complete` - this just means that you cannot do any further operations, not that it aborts all operations in the transaction that haven't finished yet. (I'm judging from the example in their docs only)

Comment: Either. Not sure about the idb library, but I think the first is better. You don't need to wait for requests to settle, the transaction settling successfully tells you that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So based on the comments it seems like they are both would work.  Since Promise.all isn't necessary seems like the first is easier to read.  Thanks.